# Flickering on certain sites with Intel HD 3000

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, google-chrome, gpu

I have a mid 2011 macbookpro 15.4 2.2ghz quad core, 16gb ram and ati 6750m w/ intel hd 3000. Mac OS X 10.9.3 & 10.10 beta.

Whenever I use chrome v35 and the graphics card is set to use the intel hd 3000, I get flickering on certain sites, 
the best one to show the issue is [bootstrap 2.3.2 site](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/) which shows up as diagonal lines. I have tested this on other 10.9.3 intel hd 3000 machines and it seems like its a bug in the graphics driver, also I have tested it on the yosemite beta and it is still an issue.

I have attached a png from my dropbox that should work in any browser & preview, but this will only work if you are using an intel hd 3000 on a laptop.

[Test Image for flickering.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9ee2fg3fa306guy/Screenshot%202014-06-13%2001.54.30.PNG)

Does anyone know of a fix other than to not use chrome?

Comment: You dropbox link seems to not be public

Comment: @Thomas I updated the link with the correct image.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue with a 17" MacBook Pro (Late 2011). I can only solve it by switching from the Intel HD 3000 card to the AMD Radeon one by using the [gfxCardStatus tool](https://gfx.io/).